# can tensorflow build spp-net model for different input image size?

Tags: python, tensorflow

my input img height is fixed but the width  range from 10 to 100000(mean is 2000).
I wanted use spp-net but tf.nn.conv2d dosen't support different size.
Is there any way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do, but conv2d DOES support different sizes. If your placeholder has shape [None, None, None, 3] for example, you can pass this as an argument to a conv2d operation (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d).

For your application, where you apply SPP after the convolutional layers, this should work!